# Why does adapter.add() create an infinite loop and crash?

Tags: java, android, loops, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I'm making an Android app and my implementation of `adapter.add()` seems to crash the app. I had to use Log tags to find that my code strangely becomes stuck in a loop. Here's the code:

```
int i =0;
if(cards.size()>0){
    Log.i("KOOL","Checked arraylist size =" + cards.size());
    while(i < cards.size()){
        Log.i("KOOL","Inside while loop");
        adapter.add(cards.get(i));
        i++;
    }
    Log.i("KOOL","Added data to adapter");
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    Log.i("KOOL","Finished OnActivityResult");
}
```

The app gets up to the Log tag "Inside while loop" and repeats it until the app crashes. I know that `cards.size()` is 2 right before the while loop so i see no reason for the app to crash. Am I using the adapter correctly? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is missing some context. Luckily I know that your adapter is of type `ArrayAdapter` and its being initialized with `cards`. When your loop starts, `cards.size()` is **2**. But then you `add` something to it, making  `cards.size()` be **3**. And then... I guess you get the point. You either add something to your adapter/list pair through the adapters `add`, or through your list `add`. If you add it to both, then you are adding it two times.

Here is the code for `ArrayAdapter::add`:

```
public void add(T object) {
    synchronized (mLock) {
        if (mOriginalValues != null) {
            mOriginalValues.add(object);
        } else {
            mObjects.add(object);
        }
    }
    if (mNotifyOnChange) notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

where `mOriginalValues` is the very same list you used to construct the adapter. `mObjects` is a filtered version of them.

Comment: @tibtof: I actually saw his entire code in a previous question, and already pointed out that he was doing this wrong.

Comment: Are you saying that adapter.add(cards.get(i)) adds to the arraylist cards? So do I need the while loop at all or will the adapter increase when cards was increased before this code?

Comment: @Daniel Katz: You don't need the loop at all, the adapter _shares_ the list you used to initialize it. The only advantage with the `add` method from the adapter, is that it will call `notifyDataSetChanged` for you.

Comment: Thanks! I guess I wasn't really sure how to use adapters. Now my app gets through that part but then crashes for another reason. In LogCat, it first says, "FATAL EXCEPTION: main" and then "java.lang.NullPointerException" and then a bunch of things. Do you know what could be going on? Do you need more of my code?

Comment: @Daniel Katz: From that error code, all I can tell you is that you are trying to dereference a `null` pointer.

Comment: Before the errors, there's a warning, "threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (groupx40020968). Is that of any significance?

Comment: @Daniel Katz: Is not. See where the `null` is dereferenced (line and number is there on the crash log) and try to figure it out. If you can't, then create an appropriate question here at SO posting your code, your crash log and pointing out to the line numbers referenced in the log.